# How to adapt my for loop to get it working with parfor of Matlab? (ODE solver)

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, ode

Ive come a long way with programming as a newbie in Matlab, but now Im really stuck. Ive tried to 'slice' the variable dy, but unfortunately it didnt work. I guess the problem lies in the fact that i is dependent on SACn. Ive done this because the ODE solver needs a vector as input, not a matrix. Can someone please help me?

This is a snippet of code:

```
parfor SACn=0:SACnum-1  
   i=19+SACn*200:1:66+SACn*200;
   dy(i-18+100,:) = alpha.*(1-y(i-18+100,:)).*(1./(1+exp(-((y(i,:)  -th1)./k1))))-beta.*y(i-18+100,:);      %#ok<*PFBNS,*PFPIE>
   dy(i-18+150,:) = alpha.*(1-y(i-18+150,:)).*(1./(1+exp(-((y(i-18+100,:)-th2)./k2))))-beta.*y(i-18+150,:); 
end
```

I tried something like this (didnt work though):

```
parfor SACn=0:SACnum-1 
   temp1dy=zeros(200,size(y,2));
   temp2dy=zeros(200,size(y,2));
      for i=19:1:66
         temp1dy(i-18+100,:) = alpha.*(1-y(i-18+100,:)).*(1./(1+exp(-((y(i,:)  -th1)./k1))))-beta.*y(i-18+100,:);      %#ok<*PFBNS,*PFPIE>
         temp2dy(i-18+150,:) = alpha.*(1-y(i-18+150,:)).*(1./(1+exp(-((y(i-18+100,:)-th2)./k2))))-beta.*y(i-18+150,:); 
      end
    dy(SACn*200+1:(SACn+1)*200,:)=temp1dy;
    dy(SACn*200+1:(SACn+1)*200,:)=temp2dy;
end
```

Additional info: I have vectorized my code in an ODE solver of Matlab, these are all the :) 's you see at the end of all variables such as y(i+18-100,:). Ive done this so that the ODE solver computes multiple values of dy for the same time point in parallel and then chooses the best option.

Please do not hesitate to ask for more details!

Comment: What error do you get?